# Sort PHP POST by a fields inputted date

Tags: php, forms, http-post

With a simple form, i have a field for users to input a date - when the fields are posted into my txt file i need them to be sorted by the date field, cant figure out a way to sort them by the date field, any ideas?

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {

$data = 'REQUEST - ' . $_POST['field1'] . ' - ' . $_POST['field2'] . ' - ' . $_POST['field3'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);}
```

Comment: date field? What date field? And sort what?

Comment: You mean everything in `mydata.txt`? You'll have to read the entire file into an array, sort that, then write it back into the file.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: one of the fields asks for the user to input a date.

Comment: so it's the existing data in the file which should be sorted, or the other POST fields should be sorted into an order before being written to the file? It's not clear. "them" is not a very good description of what precisely you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to the file in append mode, which only *adds* to the data already in the file.  You're going to have to read the file back in, 
add the data in sorted order, then re-write the entire file.

Using a database would probably be a simpler way to handle this.